# How do I get values from a complex JSON object?

Tags: json, swift, swift2, httpresponse, jsonserializer

Is it possible that someone could show me how to get the names of these pizza places printing out? My application prints out the expected `"Status Code: 200"`. However, my console only shows empty brackets `[]`. I suspect that I am not pulling values from my JSON object properly.

I'm using this link for my API.

[Link For API](https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?client_id=0F5M0EYOOFYLBXUOKTFKL5JBRZQHAQF4HEM1AG5FDX5ABRME&client_secret=FCEG5DWOASDDYII4U3AAO4DQL2O3TCN3NRZBKK01GFMVB21G&v=20130815%20&ll=29.5961,-104.2243&query=burritos)

### Question

How can I properly fetch values from my serialized JSON object?

**relevant code:**

```
    // Response
    if let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse where httpResponse.statusCode == 200, let data = data {
        print("Status Code: \(httpResponse.statusCode)")



        do {
            let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableContainers)

            if let pizzaPlaces = json["response"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
                for place in pizzaPlaces {
                    if let name = place ["name"] as? String {
                        self.PizzaClass.append(name)
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch {
            print("Error Serializing JSON Data: \(error)")
        }
        print(self.PizzaClass)


    }
}).resume()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast your `NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData` result as a `[String:AnyObject]`.

```
    let jsonObject = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(returnedData, options: .MutableLeaves) as! [String: AnyObject]
```

Once you have that all you need to do is pay attention to what you're casting. Take the code below for an example. If we want to get our `response` object using `jsonObject["response"]` what kind of data structure do we have?

```
"response": {
        "venues": [{
            //... continues
        }]
    }
```

On the left we have `"response"` which is a string, on the right we have `{}` which is an `AnyObject`. So we have `[String: AnyObject]`. You just need to think about what object your dealing with piece by piece. Below is a working example that you can just paste into your application.

**full working code:**

```
func getJson() {

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?client_id=0F5M0EYOOFYLBXUOKTFKL5JBRZQHAQF4HEM1AG5FDX5ABRME&client_secret=FCEG5DWOASDDYII4U3AAO4DQL2O3TCN3NRZBKK01GFMVB21G&v=20130815%20&ll=29.5961,-104.2243&query=burritos")!)
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

    request.HTTPMethod = "GET"
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data: NSData?, response: NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        guard let testResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse else {
            print("\(response)")
            return
        }

        guard let status = HTTPStatusCodes(rawValue: testResponse.statusCode) else {
            print("failed to unwrap status")
            return
        }
        print(status)

        switch status {
        case .Created:
            print("ehem")
        case .BadRequest:
            print("bad request")
        case .Ok:
            print("ok")

            guard let returnedData = data else {
                print("no data was returned")
                break
            }
            do {
                let jsonObject = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(returnedData, options: .MutableLeaves) as! [String: AnyObject]

                guard let response = jsonObject["response"] as? [String: AnyObject] else { return }     
                guard let venues = response["venues"] as? [AnyObject] else { return }
                guard let location = venues[0]["location"] as? [String:AnyObject] else { return }
                guard let formattedAddress = location["formattedAddress"] else { return }

                print("response: \n\n \(response)\n------")
                print("venues : \n\n \(venues)\n-------")
                print("location : \n\n \(location)\n------")
                print("formatted address : \n \(formattedAddress)")

            } catch let error {
                print(error)
            }

            // update user interface
            dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                print("update your interface on the main thread")
            }
        }  
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

place this either in its own file our outside of the class declaration,

```
  enum HTTPStatusCodes : Int {
        case Created = 202
        case Ok = 200
        case BadRequest = 404 
    }
```

Comment: Worked to perfection. Still a beginner programmer and new to Swift. Only thing is to work through it and get a understanding of what actually is happening to make it work. Thank you for your time.

Comment: No problem! It gets easier as you go, eventually everything starts to click.

Answer (score 0):

Not that this was what you are looking for, but since you are new to Swift take a look at Alamofire.  It handles JSON serialization for you.  And when you need to chain calls PromiseKit is super slick.

```
         Alamofire.request(.GET, url).responseJSON {response in

            switch (response.result) {
            case .Success(let value):

                let pizzas = JSON(value).arrayValue

                for place in pizzaPlaces {
                   if let name = place ["name"] as? String {
                     self.PizzaClass.append(name)
                   }
                }                 

            case .Failure(let error):
                if let data = response.data, let dataString = String(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
                    print("ERROR data: \(dataString)")
                }
                print("ERROR: \(error)")
            }
        }
```

Comment: Alamofire really does make life a bit simpler. Though I do recommend that developers know how to do it both ways.

Comment: @DanBeaulieu, Not sure I agree.  I'm not going to use XMLHttpRequest in Javascript because there are libraries that handle that mess for me.  So far I haven't had to break from using Alamofire and if I did, I suppose I slog through.

Comment: I'm actually in a class and can't use Alamofire as the professor won't allow it. Someone else had also mentioned this to me a couple days ago. Once I get it down like this I will check it out. Thanks for your help @Trent

Comment: @Trent we'll you certainly don't have to agree with me. I personally like to have a complete understanding of how things work. I've been a long-time ajax user myself but was very happy when my Javascript instructor showed us how to use XMLHttpRequest.